# Use TSFRESH-library to forecast values

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, time-series, feature-selection, feature-extraction

Have some issue with understanding how to use TSFERSH-library (version 0.4.0) to forecast next N-values of particular series. Below my code:

```
    # load data train/test datasets        
    train, Y, test, YY = prepare_train_test()
    # add series ID         
    train['TS_ID'] = pd.Categorical(train['QTR_HR_START']).codes
    test['TS_ID'] = pd.Categorical(test['QTR_HR_START']).codes
    # add ordered id for concrete event of series
    for id in sorted(train['TS_ID'].unique()):
        train.ix[train.TS_ID == id, 'TIME_ORDER_ID'] =  pd.Categorical(train[train.TS_ID == id]['DATETIME']).codes
    for id in sorted(test['TS_ID'].unique()):
        test.ix[test.TS_ID == id, 'TIME_ORDER_ID'] = pd.Categorical(test[test.TS_ID == id]['DATETIME']).codes
    # perform feature extraction for my signal
    extraction_settings = FeatureExtractionSettings()
    extraction_settings.IMPUTE = impute  # Fill in Infs and NaNs
    X = extract_features(train, column_id='TS_ID', feature_extraction_settings=extraction_settings).values
    XT = extract_features(test, column_id='TS_ID', feature_extraction_settings=extraction_settings).values

    # there should be as example 
    # model = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=Y, missing=np.nan)
    # model.fit()
    # model.predict(XT)
```

However, after line `X = extract_features(...)` I see at debugger following results
 [image]

It's mean that initial `X-dataset/features` (shape=(722,10) were transformed to shape (80, 1899).

Where does '80' come from? I guess from `train.TS_ID` comes. But my `XT`-dataset still contains 722-rows (9 days * 80 different series per day).

So, how can I predict for 9 days in advance? or is there only forecast for next period?

Comment: Which version of tsfresh are you using?

Comment: The latest one - 0.4

Comment: From tsfresh, you get a feature matrix with one row for each time series id. You will then have to shift your feature matrix and train the regressor to forecast the time series

Comment: tsfresh itself does not contain any estimator. You have to use sklearn, tensorflow or something similar for that.

Comment: @MaxBenChrist - could you elaborate on what is meant by "shift the feature matrix and train the regressor to forecast the time series" ? I currently have a feature matrix but not sure how to convert this into predictive modelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSFRESH is already supporting Time Series Forecast.

See details and example [here](http://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/forecasting.html) and [here](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/blob/master/notebooks/timeseries_forecasting_google_stock.ipynb)

Comment: I have the same question and not able to understand how to use the tsfresh on predictive modelling. The example on the google stock has "id" column which I do not have. I get is a 5 * 784 matrix(due to 5 features) and completly lost the time factor from the output data. How to leverage the time series facility? Any example?

Comment: Yes, I had an example ... If you can post more exactly the input-structure, I will try to adapt the example

Comment: I got this problem aswell, the notebook seems not to be up to date anymore. Does anyone have a tsfresh solution which works?